# Android Emulator slow with HAXM and GPU acceleration- what am I missing?

Tags: android, android-emulator, haxm

The Android Emulator in Android Studio is slow as molasses- mouse input lags behind by a full 2-3 seconds.

There are tons of topics on this, but many are outdated and no suggestions seem to have helped me.

HAXM is enabled.  Intel Virtualization is enabled in my BIOS.  GPU acceleration is enabled.  I'm using an x86-64 image of Android.

**Is there a setting I'm missing?**

[image: AVD Settings and cmd window confirming HAXM support]

Relevant System specs:

- Intel i5 4690K @ 4GHz
- AMD Radeon RX480 GPU
- 16 GB DDR3-1600 RAM
- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Comment: Maybe try create a new AVD?

Comment: @10101010 I had read about that working for someone- just gave it a try and it's as slow as ever. The launcher even crashed after the app drawer couldn't keep up with my inputs.

Comment: I would do this in order: change to x86, change android version, restart computer, invalidate cache, reinstall sdk tools...

Comment: Based on the screenshot, it looks like you are running an older version of Android Studio.  Update to Android Studio 3.0 or higher, ensure you running the latest Android Emulator from the SDK Manager, then create a new AVD.  Try using 32-bit x86 system image and under the graphics options, it should be set to Automatic. For faster boot time, also check out: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-emulator-2620-canary-with-quick.html